# ansible Get current index of a variable in a loop

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-awx

Say I have:

```
rn2: [x,y,z]
```

and in a task I want to output the current index of the variable it is currently using

```
- name: Output
  shell: echo "{{ item|int }}"
  loop: "{{rn2}}"
```

My expected is to output

```
0
1
2
```

but it only outputs

```
0
0
0
```

My goal is to increment the number as it loops through the list.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#tracking-progress-through-a-loop-with-index-var), we can enable additional looping options with `loop_control`. `index_var` is one of the options which enables us to access the current position in the list.

Example:

```yaml
- name: Output
  debug:
    var: my_idx
  loop: "{{ rn2 }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: my_idx
```